# Feature Layer Attribute table to Datatable and make it editable

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, wpf, attribute-table

Currently I'm using this to turn it into a data table

```
 featureCursor = layer.FeatureClass.Search(que, false);
                    row = featureCursor.NextFeature();

                    if (row != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < row.Fields.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            dataTable.Columns.Add(row.Fields.get_Field(i).Name);
                        }
                        while (row != null)
                        {
                            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                            for (int j = 0; j < featureCursor.Fields.FieldCount; j++)
                                dataRow[j] = row.get_Value(j);

                            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                            row = featureCursor.NextFeature();
                        }
                    }
```

Does anyone know a more efficient way on doing this.

Also I'm binding the data table to a datagrid, does anyone know a good way I can do this so that I can make the attribute table editable, and values reflected in the feature layer.

I can do this, but not cleanly, has anyone tried this before?

Comment: Since you are using wpf, are you wanting to leverage INotifyPropertyChanged for the binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a binding sample from ESRI.

Check it out:

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/a6eb84fb-93db-4bc3-82a9-874d8890a8ca.htm

[Same sample in ArcGIS 10 documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Bind_a_geodatabase_table_to_a_NET_control/000100000312000000/)

Comment: Tested this a while back and it worked, I think I also added a wrapper for the IRow to hide the ArcObjects interface from the .net code but that depends on what requirements you have.

Comment: how we could add Sort functionality to this wrapper ?