# How to turn an IField from Not Editable to Editable?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

so i have turned my ITable into an editable DataGridview from this post
[link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/feature-layer-attribute-table-to-datatable-and-make-it-editable).

Now i want to set some of the columns to be non editable. So what I can do is initially set my IFieldEdit.Editable_2 to false, and the column would be read only.

However, when I tried to do that and actually populate values into my field initially, it throws me exception for not editable.

So I was wondering if anyone know if i can temporary set the field to editable and then after setValue , set the editable to false again.

I have this but doesn't work:

```
bool fieldEditable = featureClass.Fields.get_Field(x).Editable;

IFieldEdit fieldEdit = (IFieldEdit)featureClass.Fields.get_Field(x);
fieldEdit.Editable_2 = true;

featureBuffer.set_Value(x, cegObject.GetPropertyValue(featureClass.Fields.get_Field(x).Name));

fieldEdit.Editable_2 = fieldEditable
```

However, the setting to true, does not work. Is there a way around this? Or is editable totally useless cause once i make a field editable, i can't even populate a value in? But i'm sure i'm just not doing it right, please help.

Thanks and Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 2):

If you create a field which is non-editable via ArcObjects or some other method, you will not be able to edit it (never) without changing the schema, which requires a lock.

I'm not sure if you can revert non-editable fields to editable via ArcObjects.

If you are concerned that a certain user will edit a field by hand, just disable that column on your UI and keep the field editable if you need to insert (calculated) values.

Comment: I've never tried it, but for ArcSDE I wonder if IField.Editable is based on column level permissions as set by the DBMS.  If so, maybe [granting permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180341.aspx) would change this?

Comment: I don't think ArcSDE grants columns permissions. Maybe Ragi could enlighten us?

Comment: @George no column permissions are used by ArcSDE. The isEditable is a bit that is flipped in the GeoDatabase system tables. If I remember it right, it used to be in the GDB_FIELDINFO table http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.1/general_topics/gdbase_sys_tables.htm . I am not sure if this has changed for ArcGIS 10. Nevertheless, George, you are completely right  to try to use the ArcObjects with a schema lock first. Then you could go the other route.